# How to add local repo to a new remote branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-remote

Need some help here: **Ideally I would just create a new repo,** but I don't have Bitbucket permissions for it in my team, and the senior engineer who does is on vacation for a couple more weeks.

I have a master branch at my repo with legacy code - I don't want to change it, too many critical systems pull from there.

I found deployment server on my network with many useful scripts which I want under version control.

My solution is to make a new branch from master, with the scripts from the deployment server on that new branch - entirely different code from the master branch. (Which is what the senior engineer has done before.)

I have initialized a local git repo.

I have added the remote origin:

```
git remote add origin https://my.username@bitbucket.site.com/scm/dev.repo.git
```

I have added a branch via bitbucket's site I'll call `deployment-scripts`.

I have locally created branch `deployment-scripts`. (But I'm checked out in master.)

***I'm terrified of doing a `git fetch` and overwriting critical scripts and everything.*** (Or does fetch not do that?) I'm hoping to do something like `git push origin deployment-scripts` and have a nice, new branch where the scripts can live.

Is this the correct path? What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

## `git fetch` won't overwrite anything

`git fetch` just updates (and creates) the references in your local repository to the remote repository. In your case this will create a reference called `origin/deployment-scripts`. The initial fetch will look something like this:

```
$ git fetch
From https://my.username@bitbucket.site.com/scm/dev.repo.git
 * [new branch]      deployment-scripts        -> origin/deployment-scripts
```

Meaning that information is fetched from the given url, where a new branch has been created named `deployment-scripts` for which a reference called `origin/deployment-scripts` was created in your local repository.

A future `git fetch` might look similar to this:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://my.username@bitbucket.site.com/scm/dev.repo.git
   fa09a74..03350ff  deployment-scripts        -> origin/deployment-scripts
```

The first three lines of the output contain some statistics about the fetched data, next comes the URL from where you fetched and then you can see that the branch deployment-scripts has changed from `fa09a74` to `03350ff` since your last fetch and the local reference was updated respectively.

## Your `git push` probably won't work

I'm assuming that the branch `deployment-scripts` that you created in bitbucket was branched off from some other branch and thus contains the commits of that branch (at least in Bitbucket server it is not possible to create an empty branch). In this case your push will fail due to the fact that the remote branch and the local branch both have changes the other one does not have:

```
$ git push origin deployment-scripts
To https://my.username@bitbucket.site.com/scm/dev.repo.git
 ! [rejected]        deployment-scripts -> deployment-scripts (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://my.username@bitbucket.site.com/scm/dev.repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

In this case a merge is required to merge together both versions, which can never happen with a push. Anyway this is not what you want to achieve, because the result would be a branch with the files from both you local `deployment-scripts` branch and the branch which was the base for creating `deployment-scripts` in Bitbucket.

## How you could solve it

### Delete the branch and create it by pushing

You could just delete the branch `deployment-scripts` in Bitbucket and push it from your local repository, which will then create the branch in Bitbucket (at least if your user is allowed to create branches):

```
$ git push origin deployment-scripts
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 250 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://my.username@bitbucket.site.com/scm/dev.repo.git
 * [new branch]      deployment-scripts -> deployment-scripts
```

### Force push the branch

Alternatively you could do a `git push --force`, which overwrites the commits on Bitbucket and thus forces your push to work.

```
$ git push --force origin deployment-scripts
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 250 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://my.username@bitbucket.site.com/scm/dev.repo.git
 + 524095e...87e6bd7 deployment-scripts -> deployment-scripts (forced update)
```

Attention: As I said this will remove all commits which were in the remote (Bitbucket) branch and not in the local branch and should only be used if you are really sure that it is the right thing to do.